# parallel() not work with the 3-arg iterate()

Tags: java, java-stream

Here is my code:

```
int count=20;
Stream.iterate(4,i->i<count,i->i+1).parallel().forEach(i -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(2000));
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
    System.out.println(i);
});
```

I expect this will go parallel, but!
When i run it, parallel() seems "dead", numbers from 4 to 19 comes with a "perfect" sequence which was not i want.
So i modified the "iterate" part like this:

```
.iterate(4,i->i+1).limit(count-4)
```

There comes fixed, the parallel() works again.
So, Why??? The iterate-limit-parallel combo seems too silly.
...Or in fact, there may be a reason?
please help me.
THX!

ps: I print the thread ID, in the first case, that always printing "main". in the second case, at least 5 threads shows up.

pps: I've tried 2000 as a big number during this weird stuck a few minutes ago. now even with several larger num(even using Integer.MAX_VALUE). Still stucks.

Comment: Did you try printing out the thread ID along with the value of `i` to see what is actually happening?

Comment: yes, i print the thread ID, in first case, that always printing "main". in second case, at least 5 threads shows up.

Comment: Why didn't you include that information in the original post? Seems pretty important, no?

Comment: ahh, sorry. i've added it:)

Comment: Stream definitions are not executed until a terminal operation is encountered... i.e. it's not _"Generate stream of integers, THEN parallelize"_.  I suspect the issue is that the three-argument `iterate()` somehow prevents parallelization, possibly because of the need to test every generated element.  But I don't know this for a fact, so this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: unfortunately I've tried ```2000``` as a big number during this weird stuck few minutes ago. Nothing changed.

Comment: I've tried Integer.MAX_VALUE. no effect.

Comment: What is your real problem? `parallel()` is not *guaranteed* to process out of order.

Comment: I can not reproduce the behavior you described for larger numbers. When use a count larger than 1024 + 4, I get parallel processing. [online demonstration](https://ideone.com/Wo9Hf8).

Comment: @Holger That is indeed the case for larger input size since the processor is not overwhelmed by the small input size. I had my comment suggesting the same but OP kept on saying that he can not reproduce it so I had to delete the previous comment. Since you have proven it using a demo, I think this question can be closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: @AniketSahrawat while I can not reproduce the “no parallel processing” behavior, I see that the parallel processing is surprisingly limited, e.g. compared to `Stream.iterate(4,i->i+1).takeWhile(i -> i<count)` which does exactly the same but uses far more threads. That part is worth investigating, so I would not close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to construct a meaningful spliterator for a stream which is generated by iterate() with 3 arguments. For example, if you have a simple stream of integers from range from 1 to 1000 you can easily split this stream into two streams, one from 1 to 500 and another from 501 to 1000 and process them in parallel. But consider this example:

```java
Stream.iterate(4,i->i<Integer.MAX_VALUE,i->i+ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInteger())
```

How would you make this stream parallel? Which number should the second thread start from? There is no way to effectively split this stream into parts without calculating all its elements first.

When you add limit() to the stream you actually buffer the results of the previous stream, so limit() can provide a non-trivial spliterator for it's internal buffer. However, neither of the streams are *guaranteed* to do something special in parallel streams, parallel() is just a "recommendation".

Comment: real thanks! this hit and solved my "why" problem in mind!

Comment: There *is* parallel support for such streams but it relies on buffering elements and the default is to buffer at least 1024 elements before passing them to another thread. As [can be demonstrated](https://ideone.com/Wo9Hf8), there is parallel processing when having more than that number of elements. But since in this example, the iteration logic is cheap and the terminal operation expense, it’s inexplainable why this doesn’t benefit better. In fact, using the semantically equivalent `Stream.iterate(4,i->i+1).takeWhile(i->i<count)` does work in parallel flawlessly. So this seems to be a bug.